# «Вы так низко пали!»

Tags: лексика, смысл, значение, устаревшие-слова

Что в наше время означает выражение «Вы так низко пали!»?

Answer (score 3):

В наше время ***низко пасть*** означает то же, что и раньше.

Толковый словарь Ожегова ([academic.ru](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/152258)):

> **пасть**
> <...>
> **4.** перен. Уронить себя в глазах окружающих, утратить доброе имя из-за предосудительного поведения. *Низко п. Падший человек. Падшая женщина* (устар.).

Толковый словарь Ушакова ([academic.ru](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/921998)):

> **ПАСТЬ**<sup>1</sup>
> <...>
> **5.** Уронить себя, утратить общественное значение, уважение, вес. *«Вы так низко пали, что у вас не осталось и следа человеческого чувства»* (Чехов). *«Не верь, что вовсе пали люди»* (Некрасов). *Он пал очень низко в глазах всех*.
> **6.** Утратить доброе имя, репутацию честной женщины вследствие порочного поведения (устар.).

[Викисловарь](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C):

> **пасть** (глагол I)
> <...>
> **6.** *перен.* морально опуститься, повести себя недостойно ◆ *До какой степени надо так низко **пасть**, чтобы пресмыкаться перед тираном-захватчиком, который мечтает поставить весь мир на колени?*

Comment: Эх, педивикия! Морально можно пример подавать, а опуститься - это аморальное поведение, аморальный поступок, повести себя недостойно (чего?) -прекрасный образец того, как не стоит формулировать смыслы.

Comment: @Буратино Вы считаете выражения "морально неустойчивый человек", "моральная деградация" неправильными? Всё нормально со смыслами. "Морально" – с точки зрения морали.   "Актер В. С. Якут острыми штрихами передает эту ломку характера честного интеллигента, раскрывает трагедию, приводящую озлобленного, **морально опустившегося** и спивающегося адвоката на дно жизни" (Борис Полевой).

Comment: Мораль - это нормы поведения, как нужно себя вести в обществе, например. Морально опустившийся - это из разряда повторения расхожих штампов, неверно сформулированных, от того, что Б Полевой его употребил, он не стал правильнее. Нормы, примеры поведения есть только для правильного, для неправильного их нет, норм, нет норм морали - аморально или внеморально.

Comment: Мораль (от лат. moralis, mores — нравственный, относящийся к нраву, характер) — совокупность особых, духовных правил, регулирующих поведение человека... - Фоксфорд.
Мораль - 1. Совокупность принципов и норм поведения людей по отношению друг к другу и к обществу; нравственность... Словарь русского языка: В 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой.
Ушакова можете глянуть и тд.
И тд. Мораль имеет только положительное значение, в этом смысл морали и этики. Моральное не может быть плохим.

Comment: Нельзя сказать: "он поступал морально, когда убивал врага"; можно сказать: "он поступал морально, когда защищал свой дом/семью/Родину от врага." Поэтому в новостях, например, говорят: уничтожены скопления живой силы противника, враг понес потери... - а не: убито столько-то. Такой способ оставаться на моральной стороне.

Comment: Насчет "повести себя недостойно" -  оно всегда употребляется в связке с чем-то(можете посмотреть примеры из литературы), нельзя сказать просто "повести себя недостойно", без обстоятельств поведения. Это ошибка плохо понимающих логику русского языка, в русском есть длинные фразы которые требуют контекст, а не просто словосочетания оторванные от контекста. Английский, в отличие от русского, идет блоками, мелкими кусками, в которых совсем не нужно делать обязательные подчинительные обороты, как в русском.

Comment: Если можно говорить **морально деградировать** (моральная деградация), то почему ж нельзя — **морально опуститься**? (http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Comment: @Буратино Не надо столько писать, это всё понятно. Но это не имеет отношения к употреблению  наречия "морально" в данном случае. Вы, извините, не слышите его здесь. Можно деградировать физически, умственно, морально; можно морально устареть. "Моральное истощение", "морально тяжёлый" и пр. и пр. На этом я закругляюсь (морально истощён :)))

Comment: @Римма Михайловна. Морально деградировать - это не русский, во-первых, а калькированный латинизм. Во-вторых, деградация - это термин "reduction of strength, value, magnitude, etc.", падение мощности, величины... магнитуда это вообще от магии))", это научный язык, а значит смешение стилей, от того что кто-то в речи примешивает без нужды научную терминологию, она не становится более содержательной и аргументированной, наоборот, это грязный трюк. Кто оценивает деградацию? Какие эксперты посчитали уровень морали, по какой шкале? Да и от этого мораль не перестает быть законами общества.

Comment: А человек в свою очередь моралью руководствуется, мораль - это законы, правила, законно деградировать - звучит бредово. Мораль деградировала - ну, криво, но вероятно, можно. Я могу только предположить, что не все кто грамоту пишет, разбираются в философии. @АлександрСтрелец , я, наверное, написал много, но вопрос не такой простой, многие в этом путаются, это нормально, ошибка идет еще с Крылова, которой вывернул наизнанку суть морали, отдаваясь западной моде. Но литераторы не философы, они не должны разбираться в морали, как и в физике или химии, дружить с логикой не обязаны.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  и я ни в коем случае не против вашей деградации. Но это не повод отказываться от развития и роста, однако, всему своё время.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова ладно, нужно еще одну вещь сказать, хотя велика вероятность, что ваше сознание взбесится. Вот смотрите, что такое философия современного общества? Её основа - это конвейер. Что такое конвейер? Это разделение функций без понимания, что, зачем, почему мы делаем, потому что рабочие люди(рабы) должны делать, а думать за них будут другие, ставить задачу будет начальник. Человек делает что-то, хорошо делает,  он молодец, а делает он гильзы для патронов, но он не задумывается ни о том, для чего гильзы, и для чего патроны и тд. Вы поняли на, что я намекаю.

Comment: Так вот, для конвейерного производства создается специальный язык - семантика. Который суть - система команд. Слово, утверждает семантика, это знак, значение имеет. Но тогда и животные обладают языком, системой знаков основанной на звуках, жестах, запахах и тд. Хотя, animal - это по определению бессловесная тварь(может иметь отношение и к человеку), движущаяся, чувствующая, но бессловесная, её слов-знаки неосмысленны, а рефлекторны, инстинктивны. И тут говорят: животные общаются. То есть у них есть что-то общее, нет они обмениваются информацией, коммуницируют, но общего, целого не осознают.

Comment: Животное не имеет представление об общем, оно обладает индивидуальность, индивидуальными особенностями, но не в состоянии осознать, обобщить целостные процессы, причины и следствия. Знаковый язык, семантика, не передает причинности образования слов, от оторван от причин существования слова. Потому что слово - это образ, а не знак, за знаки отвечает система копирования поведения окружающую, подражание (и животные это умеют тоже), а за образы, за передачу образов, отвечает мышление, дух, а не душа...

Comment: Так вот, от того, что на заборе или на грамоте написано что-то, это не становится правдой в первой инстанции, есть инструменты, способные оценить информацию, отделить зерна от плевел. И основой любой науки являются эти инструменты, методы и умение ими пользоваться. Простое повторение любой фразы - бессмысленно, назовите причину, почему так принято говорить. Если причины нет, то эту фразу нужно использовать с осторожностью, потому что у вас отсутствует представление об образе, понимание причины. И это не язык, а знаковая система, команды, которые вы привыкли повторять, по какой-то иной причине.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова вы сталкивались с нейросетями, можете отличить написанное чат-ботом от написанного человеком?