# Является ли оскорблением высказывание "Вы так низко пали!"

Tags: лексика

"Вы так низко пали!" – это оскорбление?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что мы не обсуждаем вопросы этики и поведения. Нельзя дать точный ответ.  Это будут мнения, а не ответы.

Comment: Был ли Вам полезен ответ на [вопрос о значении этого выражения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473876/Вы-так-низко-пали)?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [«Вы так низко пали!»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473876/%d0%92%d1%8b-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: Как воспринимается? Будут говорить о своем восприятии (это мнения). Как нужно воспринимать? А это кто решает? Это вопрос для ЕГЭ? Тогда нужны примеры из литературы. Вроде бы не наша это тема. И где  мнение автора, если это ДЗ. Мы можем проверить логику  рассуждений, но их нет? На mail.ru с такими вопросами приходят. Просят сделать ДЗ, а то им очень некогда. И ведь делают...

Comment: @Sharon Я просто сказал, что это не повтор. А в остальном вы правы. (Я удалил свой комментарий.)